# jQuery Mobile disables Mobile Safari's AutoFill

Tags: safari, jquery-mobile, autofill

this is specifically about MOBILE SAFARI. let's not discuss other browsers.

alright, i've got a form that works with Safari's AutoFill on the mac, it also works in a Mobile Safari if i remove jQuery Mobile. however, as soon I have jQuery Mobile firing, the AutoFill button/feature in mobile Safari stops responding. the "AutoFill" button is greyed out.

can anyone explain this?
thanks

** UPDATE / ~ANSWER **

jQuery Mobile [v1.0a4.1] just up and sets:

```
this.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
```

on

```
var textInputs = allControls.filter( "input[type=text]" );
```

...which makes all the difference.

see: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/785

Answer (score 0):

I believe I read that this was updated in version 1.1, and this was fixed.

If its not, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to reset it where you need it, either on a per page basis, or globably ...

PER PAGE:

```
$(document).delegate('yourpage','pageinit',function(){
    $(‘input[type=text]‘).attr(‘autocomplete’,'on’);
});
```

GLOBAL:

```
 $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $(‘input[type=text]‘).attr(‘autocomplete’,'on’);
 })
```

autocomplete on fix came from http://ranservices.com/2011/11/jquery-mobile-breaks-autofill-on-iphone/